# Как "подружить" bower и gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, bower

Всем привет. Использую gulp и bower, и, честно говоря, только спустя год снизошло просвещение, что использую я эту связку на 10% от всей мощи. Использую сейчас так:

Есть простой bower таск, который идет в массиве подзадач в таске `watch`:

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower({ directory: './dist/js/' })
});
```

Т.е. gulp тупо копирует все файлы из bower_components в build/js (все папки, если быть точнее).

Вопрос: какие есть пути, чтобы использовать эту связку на максимум, то есть как все файлы *.min.js перекидывать в /dist/js, а все файлы *.min.css - в /dist/css? А еще лучше, как организовать конкатенацию этих файлов в один (js и css, естесстна) - т.е. lib.min.js и lib.min.css? Как будет правильнее? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен пример использования gulp для самых распространенных задач типа склеивания и минификации?

Comment: Хороший был инструмент. Но не советую. В недавнем проекте столкнулась с некоторым количеством нерешаемых проблем из-за bower, из-за того, что его перестали поддерживать, и с обновлением компонентов такие проблемы увеличиваются, у себя в [блоге](https://bower.io/blog/) они сами предлагают альтернативы и мануалы, как максимально безболезненно мигрировать.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю что это хорошая идея, тк содержат сразу несколько .min.js / .min.css, часто дублирующих содержимое друг-друга, например bootstrap:

> bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-grid.min.css, bootstrap-reboot.min.css

Но, можно сделать это так:

```
var gulp   = require("gulp"),
  concat   = require("gulp-concat"),
  csso     = require("gulp-csso"),
  uglify   = require("gulp-uglifyjs"),
```

...

```
        gulp.task('concats', ['concat:js','concat:css'], () => {return} )

        gulp.task('concat:js', () => {
            return gulp.src("app/libs/**/*.min.js")
                .pipe(concat("concatedjs.js"))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest("app/js/test"))
        })

        gulp.task('concat:css', () => {
            return gulp.src("app/libs/**/*.min.css")
                .pipe(concat("concatedcss.css"))
                .pipe(csso())
                .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css/test"))
        })
```

В watch пихать 'concats'